# queue.remove() in Java not working

Tags: java, string, queue

I'm having problems removing an element from the queue. through extensive debugging I found that all the elements are being added, but when I try to remove one, it gives me the same element over and over.  here is the code:

```
private synchronized String accessMyQueue(char[] myInput) {
   String myOutput="";
   myOutput=convertToString(myQueue.remove());
   System.out.println("accessqueue removing:" + myOutput);
}

//and so you can see what's going on in convertToString...

private String convertToString(char[] a) {
   String myString = new String(a);
   return myString.trim();
}
```

Comment: What type of object is `myQueue`?  It's not declared in the snippet you provided.

Answer (score 8):

If `myQueue` is an instance of a standard Java class implementing the `Queue` interface, the chance that you have found a bug with it are ... well, close enough to zero that we can discount it as a possibility.

If, on the other hand, you've implemented your *own* queue then, yes, there may well be a problem but, since psychic debugging is not yet a well-established field of endeavour, you're going to have to show us the code for it :-)

I see one of two possibilities. The first is that you are somehow setting each node of your queue to the same value and you may well be removing items okay (you can detect this by adding one item then trying to remove two). This is far more likely in a language like C where you may inadvertently reuse the same pointer but it's far less likely in Java with its improved strings.

The second and most likely is that you're *not* removing the element from the queue when you call `remove`, rather you're returning the string without adjusting whatever your underlying data structure is (or, alternatively, adjusting it wrongly).

Short of seeing the code, that's about as good as I can do.

---

After your update that you were indeed using `LinkedList`, I thought I'd give it a shot with a very simple example `xx.java`:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
public class xx {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Queue<String> myQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
        myQueue.add ("abc");
        myQueue.add ("def");
        System.out.println (myQueue.size());
        System.out.println (myQueue.remove());
        System.out.println (myQueue.size());
        System.out.println (myQueue.remove());
        System.out.println (myQueue.size());
        try {
            System.out.println (myQueue.remove());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
2
abc
1
def
0
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:805)
    at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:151)
    at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:498)
    at xx.main(xx.java:14)
```

as expected.

So, bottom line is, I think we're going to need to see more of your code. It's difficult to conceive that, if there *were* a bug in `LinkedList` or the `Queue` interface, it wouldn't have been found yet by the millions of other users :-)

You also want to try putting the `System.out.println (myQueue.size());` line at a few strategic places in your code to see what's happening with the queue. This may give you an indication as to what's going on.

Comment: @pax - it is a well known fact that Jon Skeet can do psychic debugging on a good day :-)

Comment: He already knows the answer to this problem and has fixed it, but he's cleverly withholding the information to maximize the learning opportunity for all the rest of us.

Comment: oops...haha...yes, I'm using the normal java Queue...here's the declaration:

    private Queue<char[]> myQueue = new LinkedList<char[]>();

Comment: my understanding of .remove() is that it's supposed to return the string *and* remove it from the queue...is that not correct?

Comment: and if it matters, I'm using java 1.6

Comment: Ah, that changes things a little. You are indeed correct about `remove`. I still don't think it could be a bug in Java itself (see update), someone would have found it by now. I suggest you follow the protocol for quick problem solving. Show us some more code, ideally the smallest snippet that exhibits the problem.